# char pointer, read using cin.getline?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, cin

Currently doing some homework, and I got some issues. My program is crashing whenever I write in my char pointer firstname. I got char* firstname, and I try to use cin.getline(firstname, MAXTXT) where MAXTXT = 80; - This causes my program to crash, same happens to my char* lastname. I do suspect is has something to do with allocating memory? As it worked fine with my dob cin.getline.

How am I supposed to read input from user and into a char pointer? I have to use cin/cin.getline and not other kind of strings as that's a part of the homework. I can use whatever is in // after the includes.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif 

//  INCLUDE:
#include  <iostream>         //  cin, cout
#include  <cstring>          //  strcpy, strlen, strncmp
#include  <cctype>           //  toupper
#include  <cstdlib>          //  itoa
#include <iomanip>           // setw

using namespace std;

//  CONST:
const int MAXEMP = 100;     //  Max. amount of employees.
const int MAXTXT = 80;     //  Max lenght for text/string.
const int DATELEN = 7;     //  Fixed lenght for date incl \0.

                           //  ENUM:
enum Gender { female, male };

//  FUNCTION DECLARATION
void printMenu();
char read();
int  read(const char* t, int min, int max);
void newEmployee();

//  KLASSER:
class Person {                   
protected:
    char* firstname;                //  Person's firstname.
    char  dob[DATELEN];   //  Date of birth format yymmdd

public:
    Person() {
        cout << "\nfirstname: ";
        cin.getline(firstname, MAXTXT); // This crashes the program after I've written in a firstname
        cout << "\ndob (yymmdd): "; cin.getline(dob, DATELEN); // This seems to work
    }
};

class Grownup : public Person {  
protected:
    char* lastname;              //  Grownups' lastname

public:
    Grownup() {
        cout << "Lastname: "; cin.getline(lastname, MAXTXT); // The program also crashes when entering lastname
    }
};



class Employee : public Grownup {        //  Employee class
private:
    int      nr;                       //  Unique employee ID number

public:
    Employee() {
        cout << "\n\nWARNING: This message should never be displayed\n\n";
    }

    Employee(int n) {
        nr = n; // Sets the nr to whatever is sent in the parameter
    }

};

//  GLOBAL VARIABLES
Employee* employees[MAXEMP + 1];     //  Array with pointers to all the employees
int lastUsed;                //  Last used empolyee "array number"

                               //  MAIN PROGRAM
int main() {
    char command;                //  Users wish/command

    printMenu();                  //  Prints menu with command options

    command = read();             //  Read users command wish
    while (command != 'Q') {
        switch (command) {
        case 'N': newEmployee();        break;   // Add a new employee
        default:  printMenu();      break;   // Print menu
        }
        command = read();           // Reads users command wish
    }
    return 0;
}

//  FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
void printMenu() {
    cout << "\n\nCOMMANDS AVAILABLE:";
    cout << "\n\tN - New employee";
    cout << "\n\tQ - Quit";
}


char read() {                     //  reads and returns in uppercase
    char ch;
    cout << "\n\nCommand:  ";
    cin >> ch;  cin.ignore();
    return (toupper(ch));
}
//  Reads leadtext (t), read and
//    return a number between min and max
int read(const char* t, int min, int max) {
    int number;
    do {
        cout << '\t' << t << " (" << min << '-' << max << "):  ";
        cin >> number;  cin.ignore();
    } while (number < min || number > max);
    return number;
}


void newEmployee() {                    //  N - NEW EMPLOYEE:
    if (lastUsed <= MAXEMP) {   // read employeenumber
        employees[++lastUsed] = new Employee(read("Employee nummer", 0, 9999));
    }
    else cout << "\nMax amount of employees reached";
}
```

Comment: Re: "whenever I write in my char pointer" -- you **can't** read text into a **pointer**. You can read text into an **array**. So create an array and read the text into it. Yes, the name of an array in almost all contexts decays into a pointer to its first element. But a pointer is not an array.

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for your `char *` pointers?  Much better to use `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the comments in the answer below - does that look right?

Answer (score 1):

`firstname` is an uninitialised pointer.

It does not point to anything.

You asked `cin.getline` to write to the buffer it points to.

Whoops!

---

Immediately underneath you "got it right" with `dob`; why not make `firstname` an array as well?

Comment: Right, hmm. I'm not supposed to change the "protected" data as I got that as a template and I'm supposed to make code that works with the protected data. Any other way to do it without using array? do I have to make a temp variable and point to it?

Comment: @MemyselfandI: Then you'll have a dangling pointer after the temp variable dies. Perhaps your teacher is trying to get you to use dynamic allocation (`new` and `delete`) but that's a minefield that in reality you wouldn't actually step on for a program this simple.

Comment: Actually I'm suppose to use new, thanks. I got it working, however I'm not sure if this is the best way. I need to make sure I get exactly the space needed, not less not more. I do get the exact space set now, however I feel it's weird to make an array first, then use new with exact position.

`cout << "\nFirstname: "; 
char temp[MAXTXT]; cin.getline(temp, MAXTXT);
int len = strlen(temp); cout << len;
firstname = new char[len + 1];
strcpy(firstname, temp);` 

Sorry for awful formatting, don't know how to fix that on this site.

Comment: @MemyselfandI: Yeah, it is weird, and you wouldn't do it in real life, but it may be what your teacher is looking for. An alternative is to skip the local variable and just use `new` to create an array of length `MAXTXT`. Meh.

Comment: Right, but making the temp variable inside the constructor.. then it won't be deleted before the destructor is called? So basically it takes up more memory the way I do it now?

Comment: @MemyselfandI: Making the temp variable inside the constructor body it's still just a local variable inside a function. It'll be deleted _long_ before the destructor is called. Doesn't matter though as you don't ever attempt to use it again. And at these scales do not worry about amount of memory used.